# Mocking ModemManager for dbus golang client

Tags: go, dbus

I have an go program that config wwan network connection using ModemManager over D-Bus. It uses this library: https://github.com/godbus/dbus. I want to write tests for my application so I need to mock ModemManager somehow. I think that best way to do it is to create peer to peer connection and run mock ModemManager server on the other side of this connection.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [python-dbusmock](https://github.com/martinpitt/python-dbusmock), though you will need to write a ModemManager template for it since it doesn’t have one already.

Comment: Is is possible to create mock using only go?

Comment: Yes. You will essentially have to write a D-Bus service daemon which exports the same interface as ModemManager but which has your own implementation of its methods.

Comment: You should run your mock service on a separate D-Bus bus (similar to the system bus) rather than a peer to peer connection, as the bus daemon provides various bits of functionality (such as name resolution and signal multicast) which you might need. A peer to peer D-Bus connection is quite a different environment from the normal system bus, so would not be a representative test environment.

Comment: "You should run your mock service on a separate D-Bus bus". Is it possible to do with github.com/godbus/dbus library or I have to install dbus service to the host?

Comment: You’d use something like `dbus-run-session` (but set up to mock a system bus) and run your test processes under that.

Comment: Ok, I will try to describe problem that I see. I want to be able to run my test on any host that have go tools. If I will launch bus with `dbus-run-session` I have to bring `dbus` package to all systems that will use this test (personal linux & macos developer laptops, docker images that build this project, etc). Is it possible to run bus _without_ bringing packages to host system?

Comment: Most Linux systems should have `dbus-run-session` installed already, or some equivalent provided by the D-Bus daemon that they use (such as `dbus-broker-launch`). If you want to run a bus without installing a bus daemon, you’ll have to write a bus yourself, which is a huge amount of work.